# Trying to create table in fusion tables returns Invalid credentials

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-api-python-client

***This is the altered code of the sample code given in google to access Fusion tables via python. I want to create table in fusion tables and then insert data... using the post request I managed to write this following code to create a Table by sending a post request. But this
is returning an "invalid credentials" error and location being the> Header. Kindly help... or suggest a simple code to create table and insert in Fusion table(data is in txt file). Im very new to this. kindly help.***

Complete CODe:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Copyright (C) 2011 Google Inc.

""" Demostrates use of the new Fusion Tables API

"""

import urllib2, urllib, simplejson, sys, httplib

client_id = "996027904153.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client_secret = "secret-given"#
redirect_uri = "my localhost"
api_key = "my api_key is given"
tableid = "1jCqbPu5PjNsczx7cDl3y9EJtSUgNePbvXT7-x70"

class RunAPITest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.access_token = ""
        self.params = ""

    def main(self):
        print "copy and paste the url below into browser address bar and hit enter"
        print "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?%s%s%s%s" % \
            ("client_id=%s&" % (client_id),"redirect_uri=%s&" % (redirect_uri),
  "scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables&","response_type=code")
        code = raw_input("Enter code (parameter of URL): ")
        data = urllib.urlencode({
           "code": code,
           "client_id": client_id,
            "client_secret": client_secret,
              "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
               "grant_type": "authorization_code"
                        })
        serv_req = urllib2.Request(url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
             data=data)
        serv_resp = urllib2.urlopen(serv_req)
        response = serv_resp.read()
        tokens = simplejson.loads(response)
        access_token = tokens["access_token"]
        print access_token
        self.access_token = access_token
        print "CREATE TABLE"
        data='''{ "name": "Insects","columns": [{"name": "Species","type": "STRING"},{"name":                      "Elevation","type": "NUMBER"},{"name": "Year","type": "DATETIME"}],"description": "Insect Tracking Information.","isExportable": "true"}'''
        headers={}
        headers['Authorization']=access_token
        headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
        print headers
        response = self.runRequest("POST","/fusiontables/v1/tables/",data,headers)
        json_response = simplejson.loads(response)
        return json_response

   def runRequest(self, method, url, data=None, headers=None):
        request = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.googleapis.com")
        if data and headers: 
                  request.request(method, url, data, headers)
        else: 
                  request.request(method, url)
        response = request.getresponse()
        print response.status, response.reason
        response = response.read()
        print response
        return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
        api_test = RunAPITest()
        api_test.main()
```

Comment: I am interested in this too